# Is there a pythonic way to replace global variable or class variable

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables

I used class variables to replace avoid using global variables,But I think it's not a pythonic way,Can any one give me a better way?

class variable way:

```
class A(object):
    _func_map=dynamic_load_from_module()
    _ad_map = dynamic_load_from_another_module()
    @classmethod
    def check_status(cls,host,port,user):
        #do something other
        return cls._func_map[user].verify()
    @classmethod
    def check_ad(cls,host,port,user):
        #do something other
        return cls._ad_map[user].check()
```

global variable way:

```
_global_func_map = dynamic_load_from_module()
_global_ad_map = dynamic_load_from_another_module()
def check_status(host,port,user):
    #do something other
    global _global_func_map 
    return _global_func_map[user].verify()
def check_ad(host,port,user):
    #do something other
    global _ad_map
    return _ad_map[user].check()
```

Comment: Just use an `__init__` function and define your variables there.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the most pythonic way is a module:

```
#!/usr/env/bin/python
def dynamic_load_from_module(): pass
def dynamic_load_from_another_module(): pass

fun_map = dynamic_load_from_module()
ad_map = dynamic_load_from_another_module()
```

So you use it like a module:

```
from module import fun_map, ad_map
class Foo(object):

    @classmethod
    def check_ad(cls,host,port,user):
        return ad_map[user].check()
```

---

But if you need them to be called at the construction of your instance, you may want to do something like

```
#!/usr/env/bin/python
def dynamic_load_from_module(): pass
def dynamic_load_from_another_module(): pass
```

(So you just define functions within the module)

```
from module import dynamic_load_from_module, dynamic_load_from_another_module

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._fun_map = dynamic_load_from_module()
        self._ad_map = dynamic_load_from_another_module()
```

Or if you need them to be called at the construction of the instance but still be class' attribute:

```
from module import dynamic_load_from_module, dynamic_load_from_another_module

class Foo(object):
    _fun_map = dynamic_load_from_module()
    _ad_map = dynamic_load_from_another_module()
```

---

There lot of other ways (properties, class method, static methods, etc..), but I'm pretty sure the module is the most pythonic one. Moreover it's really easy to setup, read and understand - so why not.